# Drupal 7 New User Creating programmatically?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Drupal 7 i need to crate New User with the Code (not via the Panel manually).

When i test with this chunk of example code i googled, in the Drupal:

```
$form_state = array();
$form_state['values']['name'] = 'robo-user';
$form_state['values']['mail'] = 'robouser@example.com';
$form_state['values']['pass']['pass1'] = 'password';
$form_state['values']['pass']['pass2'] = 'password';
$form_state['values']['op'] = t('Create new account');
drupal_execute('user_register', $form_state);
```

It showing: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_execute() in ......`

How can i make it work or any other simple way like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code you found is for Drupal 6 and out-of-date. `drupal_execute()` was renamed [`drupal_form_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) in Drupal 7 and the form is now `user_register_form`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, which really handles programmatically rather than mimicking the user registration behavior.

```
$account->is_new = TRUE;
$account->status = TRUE;

$edit['name'] = $name;
$edit['mail'] = $mail;
$edit['status'] = 1;
$edit['init'] = $name;

$newuser = user_save($account, $edit);

//send email if you want
_user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $newuser);
```